# How to open kendo window popup on page load?

Tags: jquery

Here is my query:

I want to open kendo window popup by default on page load:

Thank you in advance

```
  var flag_model_popup = $("#flag_model_popup");

  flag_model_popup.kendoWindow({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 582,
                    height:620,
                    title: "",
                    visible: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false


                }).data("kendoWindow");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is working code

```
}).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```